# Function Iterations Inquiry

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have been given the task of creating a function that iterates through an array. Below is what I have, but I’m getting `undefined`. What am I missing?

```js
function lookingForDave(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr; i++) {
    if (array.forEach === 'Dave') {
      return 'I found him';
    } else {
      return 'Not Dave';
    }

  }
}
var testArray = ['Dave'];

console.log(lookingForDave(testArray));
```

Comment: That code makes no sense. How would an array method equal a string? You're not even using the parameter name consistently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use find rather than a for loop. It looks as if you want to return after you first find a match. Array.find will return the value of the first matching criteria.

In the below case if the element in the array is equal to Dave. If there is no match then we will iterate through each item in the array and return undefined.

We can then use the  conditional (ternary) operator to test if an item was found.

```
function lookingForDave (arr){
   const found = arr.find(el => el === 'Dave');
   return found ? 'found him' : 'Not Dave'; 
} 
let testArray = ['Dave'];
lookingForDave(testArray);
```

[conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

[Array find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: that works only if the element itself is not a falsy value, because `find` returns the element.

Comment: True, Thanks for highlighting that.

Comment: just another hint, it is a [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Answer (score 4):

You need to check an element of the array against a value, then return if found, otherwise return `'Not Dave'` at the end of the function.

If you return at the first check of the value and return not found, you omit all other elements for checking.

```js
function lookingForDave(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] === 'Dave') {
            return 'I found him';
        }
    }
    return 'Not Dave';
}

var testArray = ['Dave'];

console.log(lookingForDave(testArray));
```

Another solution could be to use [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and return the wanted string.

```js
function lookingForDave(array) {
    return array.includes('Dave')
        ? 'I found him'
        : 'Not Dave';
}

var testArray = ['Dave'];

console.log(lookingForDave(testArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another solution:

```
function lookingForDave(array) {
    return array.some(el => el === "Dave") ?
    "It's Dave" :
    "Not Dave!";
}



var testArray = ["Dave", "Bob", "Sam"];

console.log(lookingForDave(testArray));
```

Here's hoe it works:
`some()` takes a function that is run for each and every element in your array. The function that you pass as an argument must return a **truthy** or **falsy** value.
If *any* of those return statements is truthy, `some()` returns true.
Using a the ternary operator we check if it's true we return "It's Dave" and otherwise "Not Dave!".

Hope that helps!